# Connection with a singleton patterns returns client has already open

Tags: javascript, postgresql, singleton

I'm newbien with Singleton pattern and I try to make a singleton to get a diferent client each time I make a call to it.

The code of my singleton is:

```
const Singleton = (() => {
    var instance;

    function createInstance(){
        let client  = new Client({
            user: config.db_postgres.user,
            password: config.db_postgres.password,
            database: config.db_postgres.name,
            host: config.db_postgres.host,
            //ssl: config.db_postgres.ssl            
        });
        //await client.connect();
        return client;
    }

    return{
        getInstance: function (){
            if (!instance){
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

module.exports.Singleton = Singleton;
```

And when I try to use different instances of the singleton is in this test:

```
describe("Read information from database", () => {
    test("Test 1: Read information from table: tbl001_clientPG", async () => {
        let result;
        try{
            let clientPG = Singleton.getInstance();
            await clientPG.connect();
            result = await clientPG.query("select * from tbl010_country");
            await clientPG.end();
        }catch (err){
            console.log(err.stack);
        }
        expect(result.rows.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
    test("Test 2: Get data from table: tbl002_accesses", async() => {
        let result;
        try{
            let clientPG = Singleton.getInstance();
            await clientPG.connect();
            result = await clientPG.query("select * from tbl012_destinations");
            await clientPG.end();
        }catch (err){
            console.log(err.stack);
        }
        expect(result.rows.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
});
```

The first test works fine but the second returns me this error:

```
 Error: Client has already been connected. You cannot reuse a client.
```

And I don't know why I get this error because the goal of the Singleton is to get different instances.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*I try to get a different client each time I make a call to it.*" - then you should **not** use a singleton, but a simply factory function. The purpose of the singleton pattern is to get the same *single* instance every time you make a call to `getInstance`, which is precisely what you don't want.

Comment: @Bergi Ok!!! So, a singleton is what I have done previously in the code of my other question. Is there any way to open and close the connection when you need it? Or in this case is a bad practice? Because what I'm trying to do since the beggining is to found a way to open and close the connection when you are going to use it.

Comment: You should create a new client for each connection, or even better, acquire one from a pool.

Comment: @Bergi thank you very much for your appreciated help!!! You have helped me a lot!!!